# Is there a way of determining the last entry when looping through an array? Create a find command from an array

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a find command options string using entries from an array but on the last entry of the array I would like to add a different string.

```
EXT=(sh mkv txt)

EXT_OPTS=(-iname)

# Now build the find command from the array
for i in "${EXT[@]}"; do
    #echo $i
    EXT_OPTS+=( "*.$i" -o -iname)
done
```

cheers

EDIT:

So now I am going with:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXT=(sh mkv txt)

EXT_OPTS=()
# Now build the find command from the array
for i in "${EXT[@]}"; do
    EXT_OPTS+=( -o -iname "*.$i" )
done

# remove the first thing in EXT_OPTS
EXT_OPTS=( "${EXT_OPTS[@]:1}" )

# Modify to add things to ignore:

EXT_OPTS=( "${EXT_OPTS[@]:-1}" )
EXT_OPTS=( '(' "${EXT_OPTS[@]}" ')' ! '(' -iname "*sample*" -o -iname "*test*" ')' )

#echo "${EXT_OPTS[@]}"

searchResults=$(find . -type f "${EXT_OPTS[@]}")

echo "$searchResults"
```

for me produces this:

```
./Find2.sh
./untitled 2.sh
./countFiles.sh
./unrar.sh
./untitled 3.sh
./untitled 4.sh
./clearRAM.sh
./bash_test.sh
./Test_Log.txt
./untitled.txt
./Find.txt
./findTestscript.sh
./untitled.sh
./unrarTest.sh
./Test.sh
./Find.sh
./Test_Log copy.txt
./untitled 5.sh
./IF2.sh
```

Comment: @Jesse_b sorry edited to include the array. I'm just testing it on whats in the current folder and then use it somewhere else when its working correctly

Comment: Can you show example input and output?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor as in where I finally use the string ? and what i get out ?

Comment: Yes. As in what you put in, and what you get out. (Maybe this script has no input, that is fine. I suspect it may not.)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor edited post to include full code and the result for me.

Comment: What is the input? and can you explain what should be different about the last one. I can not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the options in another order, then delete the first element:

```
EXT=(sh mkv txt)

EXT_OPTS=()
# Now build the find command from the array
for i in "${EXT[@]}"; do
    EXT_OPTS+=( -o -iname "*.$i" )
done

# remove the first thing in EXT_OPTS
EXT_OPTS=( "${EXT_OPTS[@]:1}" )
```

If you don't use `$@` for anything, it's neater looking:

```
EXT=(sh mkv txt)

# Empty $@
set --

# Now build the find command from the array
for i in "${EXT[@]}"; do
    set -- -o -iname "*.$i"
done

# remove the first thing in $@
shift

# assign to EXT_OPTS (this would be optional, you could just use "$@" later)
EXTS_OPTS=( "$@" )
```

I prefer adding `-o -iname "*.$i"` to the intermediate array, because `"*.$i" -o -iname` is difficult to read.  Adding `-o -iname "*.$i"` to `$@` also makes it *really* easy to just `shift` off the first `-o` after the loop.

---

To combine with a few exclusions (names to ignore):

```
extensions=( sh mkv txt )
ignore_patterns=( '*sample*' '*test*' )

include=()
# Now build the find command from the array
for ext in "${extensions[@]}"; do
    include+=( -o -iname "*.$ext" )
done

# Do the ignore list:
ignore=()
for pattern in "${ignore_patterns[@]}"; do
    ignore=( -o -iname "$pattern" )
done

# combine:
EXT_OPTS=( '(' "${include[@]:1}" ')' ! '(' "${ignore[@]:1}" ')' )
```

Note the parentheses added to sort out the precedence of the tests.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the next bit which is to exclude files with 'test' and 'sample' in the file name. It doesn't seem to work if the either of those words are at the front of the filename.

Comment: @madmiddle See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you fella all working as i'd hoped.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easiest just to fix the array after the fact. After `done`, adding

```
unset 'EXT_OPTS[-1]'
unset 'EXT_OPTS[-1]'
```

[will remove](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-unset) the last two values (`-o` and `-iname`), and then you can add others if you want (or just replace them to begin with).

It might be *slightly* easier still just to add a redundant condition:

```
EXT_OPTS+=( "*.${EXT[0]}" )
```

if your real situation is a bit more complicated, but for this one I would just fix it as above.

Comment: @michealHomer that simple. wow thank you. I needed the last parts to be remove and then add the options to ignore files with 'sample' and 'test' in them

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of determining the last entry when looping through an array?

Just to answer the question as literally stated, I don't think you can do that directly. But you could of course count the elements while looping and compare that against the array size:

```
test=(foo bar blah qwerty)
count=${#test[@]}
n=1
for x in "${test[@]}"; do
   last=""
   if [[ $((n++)) -eq count ]]; then
        last=" (last)"            # last element, add a note about that
   fi
   printf "%s%s\n" "$x" "$last"
done
```

Of course in your case, you could also make the *first* item the exceptional one.